MJPEG recording usinng Node and fluent-ffmpeg
I am creating a node application to record a live MJPEG stream 24 hours in chunks of 2 minutes.
Please see the code below.
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// MJPEG stream URL (replace with your stream's URL)
const mjpegStreamUrl = 'http://192.168.195.62:8080/';

// Directory to store recorded files
const outputDir = path.join(__dirname, 'recordings');

// Ensure the output directory exists
if (!fs.existsSync(outputDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(outputDir, { recursive: true });
}

// Function to start recording
function recordStream() {
    const timestamp = new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-'); // Timestamp for file name
    const outputFilePath = path.join(outputDir, `recording-${timestamp}.mp4`);

    console.log(`Recording started: ${outputFilePath}`);

    // Start recording using ffmpeg
    ffmpeg(mjpegStreamUrl)
        .inputFormat('mjpeg')
        .outputOptions([
            '-c:v copy', 
            '-f mp4' 
        ])
        .duration(120) 
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log(`Recording finished: ${outputFilePath}`);
            recordStream(); 
        })
        .on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(`Error recording stream: ${err.message}`);
            setTimeout(recordStream, 5000); 
        })
        .save(outputFilePath);
}
recordStream();

I am always hit with the below error
Recording started: D:\Recording Node\recordings\recording-2024-09-10T05-09-34.554Z.mp4
Error recording stream: ffmpeg exited with code 4294967274: Conversion failed!

Kindly tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

JPEG is not a valid codec for MP4 container.  What's wrong with outputting MJPEG as it is?
